# ED25519 SSH Connection Hangs/Time-outs

Tags: server, ssh, timeout

I am battling what I would call an unusual SSH issue with Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04. I'm in deployment of Ansible Tower and Kubernetes (K3S); initially using 22.04 but discovered AWX could not connect to remote host over SSH. I can connect to all hosts via ssh with same private/public keys with no problem from other clients. And yet, manually transferring private key to AWX host will not establish a connection. After days of troubleshooting to no avail, I dumped all servers and reverted to 20.04; same results.

I'm using ed25519 keys for the added security. I've considered reverting to RSA, but I'm looking to have some future proofing. Verbose logging of all connection attempts are freezing at "debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY" for several minutes; to eventually timeout.  I've verifed the connections are being allowed across PFsense firewall VLAN  rules.